# can not access ini file from other directory with pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, ini

I have this statment

```
import os

from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()

configfilename = "./config.ini"
print(config.read(configfilename))
```

which returns

```
['./config.ini']
True
```

for some reasons when I move the ini file to another path

like `configfilename = "config_file/config.ini"`
I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config_file/config.ini'
[]
False
```

with other editors I get no errors whatsoever
I have Pycharm Community and Proffesional with different setups and get the same error

Comment: Pass the absolute path of the file in the code.

Comment: absolute path is working, but why not the relative ?

Comment: Great! Problem solved.

Comment: would be nice to know why the relative part is not working

Comment: Relative part would also work. You need to pass the proper path of the new dir from the current dir which Pycharm is using. Something like `configfilename = "../../config_file/config.ini"`

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(os.getcwd())` to show the current directory. You may need to change the working directory manually.

[image]

Comment: looks the same in my settings